# Проблема с реализацией интерфейсов в Go

Tags: golang, интерфейс

недавно начал изучать Go и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Первая структура имеет метод с value receiver, а вторая структура с point receiver. Обе структуры реализуют интерфейс. В первом случае я присваиваю интерфейсу структуру  по значению и по ссылке. Ошибки почему-то не выдает, хотя метод первой структуры имеет рисивер на значение, а не на адрес. Но во втором случае, если я пытаюсь  передать вторую структуру не по ссылке, а по значению, то возникает ошибка, т.к интерфейс не реализуется. Сильно запутался и не могу понять, почему в первом случае интерфейс реализуется при передачи структуры и по значению, и по ссылке.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ifRealization interface {
    init()
}
type firstStruct struct{}

func (f firstStruct) init() {
    fmt.Printf("Init; Type: %T Value: %v", f, f)
}

type secondStruct struct{}

func (f *secondStruct) init() {
    fmt.Printf("Init; Type: %T Value: %v", f, f)
}

func main() {
    var first ifRealization = firstStruct{}
    var second ifRealization = &firstStruct{} // Ошибки нет
    first.init()
    second.init()

    var f ifRealization = secondStruct{} //Type does not implement 'ifRealization' as the 'init' method has a pointer receiver
    var s ifRealization = &secondStruct{} //Ошибки нет
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерфейс - это перечень методов с заданными сигнатурами. Тип `T` реализует интерфейс, если набор методов (*method set*) типа `T` включает в себя множество методов интерфейса.

Теперь о том, как вычисляется method set: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets

- Если `T` является **не-указателем**, то набор методов складывается из методов для типа `T`, то есть методов, реализованных как `func (obj T) Method(...)`
- Если `T` является **указателем**, то есть `T = *T1`, то набор методов складывается из методов для типа `*T1` и самого типа `T1`, то есть методов, реализованных как `func (obj *T1) Method(...)` **и** как `func (obj T1) Method(...)`

Для не-указателя `firstStruct` вы реализовали метод `func (f firstStruct) init() {}`. В соответствии с правилами вычисления `method set` метод `init` входит в набор методов как для типа `firstStruct`, так и для типа `*firstStruct`. Именно поэтому переменная `second`, являющаяся указателем, реализует интерфейс `ifRealization`.

В случае `secondStruct` вы реализовали метод `init` для **указателя**: `func (f *secondStruct) init()`. Следовательно, этот метод входит в method set для типа `*secondStruct`, но не входит в набор методов типа `secondStruct`. Как следствие, переменная `s` реализует интерфейс, а переменная `f` - нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все стало понятно.